# ExtJS GET action to store returns 500 in FireFox

Tags: javascript, extjs, asp.net-web-api, store

I'm getting the strangest behavior from FireFox when loading data from a Web API GET request whereas other browsers do this perfectly. Here is what Fiddler can tell me when I use Firefox:

```
  3817  500 HTTP    localhost:52543 /api/Tasks/Get?_dc=1442848131483&page=1&start=0&limit=25    5 403   private application/xml; charset=utf-8  firefox:138020
```

Same action, other browser (Chrome):

```
3954   200  HTTP    localhost:52543 /api/Tasks/Get?_dc=1442848159073&page=1&start=0&limit=25    1 508   no-cache; Expires: -1   application/json; charset=utf-8 chrome:2808
```

I'm unable to catch the error in the Application_Error, nor do I receive errors in the exception listener on the client-side, so I suspect something is going wrong between returning the result to the client and the client processing the results, but I have no clue at all where the problem might be situated.

Here is the store definition:

```
Ext.define('SchedulerApp.store.UnplannedTaskStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'UnplannedTask',
autosync: false,
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    api: {
        read: '/api/Tasks/Get',
        add: '/api/Tasks/Add',
        update: '/api/Tasks/Update',
        destroy: '/api/Tasks/Destroy'
    },
    actionMethods: {
        create: 'POST',
        read: 'GET',
        update: 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true
    }
},
listeners: {
    load: function (sender, node, records) {
    },
    exception: function (proxy, response, options) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', response.status + ": " + response.statusText);
    }
}
```

});

and the model:

```
Ext.define('UnplannedTask', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'Importance', type: 'float' },
    { name: 'Category', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'TaskNo', type: 'float' }
]
```

});

This is what I have in the Web API:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public async Task<dynamic> Get(string page, string start, string limit)
    {
        // Get items from database with request information from the Kendo Grid Control
        PagingResult<TaskViewModel> tasks = await this.Worker.GetPagedTasksAsync(int.Parse(page), int.Parse(limit), null, null);

        // Map them to store objects
        var convertedTasks = new SchedulerTasksViewModel()
        {
            total = tasks.Count,
            data = tasks.Items.Select(x => new SchedulerTask()
            {
                Importance = x.Importance,
                Category = x.Category,
                TaskNo = x.TaskNumber
            }).ToArray()
        };

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, convertedTasks);
        return response;
    }
```

Could it be a browser issue or am I missing something on the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this header to your proxy:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json" }
```

Comment: BAM! Spot on, you're the hero of the day! Great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to elaborate a bit. The error is thrown by the XML serializer; you don't see the details because IIS does not send them to the front.

I would recommend to modify all your API calls such that they work with XML as well - even if your front-end does not use XML. It's far easier to debug if you can just open API calls in new browser tabs and the XML serializer does not mask code errors with serialization errors.

To see the error message, you would have to allow your development IIS to bring errors to the front:

1. Open the IIS7 manager
2. Select the Website and on its features view, double click on “Error Pages”.
3. Right click and select the “Edit Feature Settings…” or select the same from the Actions pane (in the right hand side)
4. Select the “Detailed errors” radio button and click on OK

([Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers.aspx))

My best guess is that you just have to decorate some types or properties with `[DataContract]`, `[DataContractAttribute]` or `[DataMemberAttribute]`. The error message will tell you which ones and how to decorate.

Another thing entirely: If you use more than one Ajax request, I'd recommend to define an override on the Ajax proxy. That way you can't forget one:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.override.Ajax", {
    override:'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    headers:{'Accept':'application/json'}
});
```